# Problem in showing user profile information in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble showing user profile information in a profile page from the database which gives me Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project_one\resources\views\profile.blade.php)

I have attached my code below

Route

```
Route::get('/profile', function() {
    return view('profile', [
        "title" => "Profile",
        "profile" => Profile::all(),
        "user" => User::all()
    ]);
});
```

Profile Table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Function in User Model

```
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
```

Blade template

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="floatingName">Name</label>
        <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i wanted to show a certain user information which consists of his name, address, etc

Comment: why not fetch user form his id ?

Comment: you want the profile of current logged in user? then use ` "user" => auth()->user()` and `"profile" => auth()->user()->profile`

Answer (score 0):

your user query "user" => User::all() you are passing to the profile page is the whole users in you DB which is a collection of many users you can't get a specific user name with that......if you want the name of the currently logged in user you will have to use

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
     <label for="floatingName">Name</label>
     <p>{{ auth()->user()->name }}</p>
</div>
```

without passing the user collection from your route.

or you can also pass the user logged in user through your route with this

```
Route::get('/profile', function() {
    return view('profile', [
        "title" => "Profile",
        "profile" => Profile::all(),
        "user" => auth()->user(),
    ]);
});
```

and in your view

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
     <label for="floatingName">Name</label>
     <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your solutions but it gives me this error instead ErrorException
Attempt to read property "name" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project_one\resources\views\profile.blade.php). How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the user currently logged in?

Comment: If the user is not currently logged in then you have to pass the user id into the route will be "user"=>User::find(id) instead of the "user"=> auth()->user()

Comment: i have tried the way you have advised but I got this error now. I am so sorry for asking too many questions but I really need the help. This is the route (Route::get("profile/{id}", [ProfileController::class, 'findUser']);) and this is the blade ( <h6><a href="profile/{{ $user['id'] }}" style="text-decoration: none">{{ $user->name }}</a></h6> ) and I got this error: 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH.

Comment: No worries at all svt! I am here to always help out....Okay this issue is from the route conflicting.. Please confirm if you have another route that is of the pattern "profile/{some-other-content}" with a different method like PUT,POST,PATCH

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have one route that i use to update the profile using PATCH but it only consists of /profile.

Comment: okay nice! then it means the href="profile/{{ $user['id'] }}" is outputting just "/profile" so change $user->id and see if you get same result. if you do then dd($user) in your findUser method in the controller

Comment: can you add your profile controller code sample to you intial question to we can see how it is constructed?

Comment: this is what i used for that route in the profilecontroller                                            public function findUser ($id) {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('profile', ['user'=>$user]);
    }

Comment: okay fine! before the return view.... dd($user); if it gives you result or a null

Comment: it gives me error exception undefined variable user

Comment: I believe your implementation is `public function findUser($id) { $user = User::find($id); dd($user); }` you are not suppose to get the "undefined variable user"

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/profile', function() {
    return view('profile', [
        "title" => "Profile",
        "profile" => Profile::all(),
        "user" => User::all()  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    ]);
});
```

**User:all()** returns collection of all users from the Database, For your case to get specific user on session use **auth()->user()**

Your Route should look like this

```
Route::get('/profile', function() {
    return view('profile', [
        "title" => "Profile",
        "profile" => Profile::all(),
        "user" => auth()->user(), // HERE IS THE SOLUTION
    ]);
});
```

Then you can use variable **$user** in a blade and get name of specific user

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
     <label for="floatingName">Name</label>
     <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
</div>
```